# Disable automatic merging files when pulling from another branch

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, tortoisegit

How do you stop TortoiseGit and/or SourceTree from performing an automatic merge when you pull from another branch?

I want to manually merge (with KDiff3 or whatever external diff/merge program) all files that have been changed in both the checked out branch and the branch I'm pulling from.

Apparently, merging is done automatically (and badly) by default, and it completely messed up my project files.

Answer (score 0):

1. Setup KDiff3 as external program for diff/merge
2. Fetch
3. Compare revisions
4. Diff each file and merge manually

---

External Program Setting: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html

diff with KDiff3:

`C:\Path-To\kdiff3.exe %base %mine --L1 %bname --L2 %yname`

merge with KDiff3:

`C:\Path-To\kdiff3.exe %base %mine %theirs -o %merged --L1 %bname --L2 %yname --L3 %tname`

Comment: Fetch won't start any external merge program (like KDiff3) for manual merging.

Comment: Looks like you want "pull + amend last commit in one step"?

Comment: No. I want to pull from another branch, but I want to use KDiff3 (or similar) for merging files that are modified in both branches, rather than have Git do it blindly without user intervention.

Comment: Fetch, compare with two branch, and merge manully?
Could you please provide a testing repository? I want to know the reason exactly why you want to merge "manually". (I think git is smart enough on merge.)

Comment: No, Git messed up my project files, so it's obvoiusly not smart enough. But never mind my reasons, let's just get back to my actual question: How can I make TortoiseGit and/or SourceTree invoke KDiff3 when I merge?

Comment: Fetch => get remote ref and related commit. Compare revisions => get Changed Files. Diff => manual merge.

Comment: BTW, using KDiff3 for diff/merge, see https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html